# Redis golang перехват события удаления

Tags: golang, сессия, события, redis

Данный код выводит сообщение о удалении, уже после удаления сессии. Как сделать, что бы перед удалением сессии я мог с ней что нибудь сделать`pubsub, err := client.Subscribe("*") /*подписывается на все каналы*/
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("PubSub creation error!:", err)
    }

```
defer pubsub.Close()

//err = pubsub.PSubscribe("__keyspace@0__:mykey del") // задает шаблон канала
err = pubsub.PSubscribe("__keyevent@0__:expired") // задает шаблон канала
if err != nil {
    log.Panic("PubSub subscribe error!:", err)
}

log.Println("Redis watch expired running!")

for !stop {

    // засыпает на 5 секунд
    msgi, err := pubsub.ReceiveTimeout(time.Duration(0) * time.Second) //ждет 5 секунд
    fmt.Println(msgi)

    if err != nil {

        continue
    }

    switch msg := msgi.(type) { //смотрит тип сообщения если есть

    case *redis.Subscription:
        log.Println("Redis subscribed to", msg.Channel) //подписка на канал

    case *redis.Message: //тип сообщение
        if msg.Pattern == "__keyevent@0__:expired" { //Событие прилетело с таким то названием
            var ss SoftRole
            ss.getRedisRole(msg.Payload) //эта функция возвращаю структуру с данными
            fmt.Println(ss)
            fmt.Println("Session dead!", msg.Payload) //название ключа который был удален
        }
    default:
        log.Println("Redis pubsub unknown message!:", msgi)
    }

}`
```

Вот действие которое я делаю в случае сообщения, должно выполниться перед удалением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то никак. И к Go это отношения не имеет. В Redis нет никакого события перед удалением, когда пришел `EXPIRED`, ключа уже нет.

Но если сильно хочется и вы управляете созданием сессий, можете использовать "колхозный" метод с созданием второго ключа и отловом событий уже по нему. Т.е. создаете, например, элемент `session:a` с данными сессии без срока действия и одновременно с этим создаете пустой элемент `exp:session:a` с необходимым сроком действия и подписываетесь на события по нему. Когда приходит `EXPIRED` для `exp:session:a`, `session:a` все еще доступен и вы можете удалить его уже самостоятельно. Минусы такого подхода, я думаю, очевидны, но если надо, это вариант.

Comment: @HunterNomad, пока вы не наберете несколько десятков баллов (50 баллов кажется), вы не можете комментировать, но можете задавать вопросы и отвечать ответы.